# Link in view to controller task resets state variables

Tags: joomla, controller, components, task, state

I have a task in my controller that I call from an URL in the view, like this:

```
echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=myComponent.myFunction');
```

The task gets the model and actions one of the model's methods, which should return a list of objects based on state variables set from a form in the view's POST.  It seems when I click the anchor and the task is loaded - the state disappears.

Can anyone tell me why?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a new request your post data is no longer available.

You need to store information in session (setUserState) or somewhere else (db?) if you want to keep it across calls.

setUserState is a convenient feature of Joomla to store (small) pieces of info into session in an easy way: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables

Comment: Many Thanks, I started using the setUserState instead of just setState and now it all works - just have to change all the filters so they use the setUserState now! So what is the difference between setState and setUserState?  I'm quite confused by why setState even exists?  So in my populateState task, as well as using `$this->setState()` I'm going to include `$app->setUserState()`? Something seems a little untidy?

Comment: typically you would use JModel->setState to set some parameters of the model, i.e. list ordering or filtering options, while setUserState is used to preserve user data across subsequent calls. I guess you would set the model state with the userState variables in the task=myComponent.myFunction for consistency, but it's really depending on your business logic